Mirror Ipad screen to pc with java API
I need to mirror an ipad screen to a window desktop on a pc, I'll use this functionality for a drone project.
I've googled a lot only to find propietary solutions from DJI and iMyFone MirrorTo (this last one is what I want to achieve), the  openAirPlay is not suitable since it is to mirror among only Apple Devices.
Can you help me with some Java/Python Api?

did you find any solution? Please suggest if any
